# how to call procedure on dynamic form

Tags: c#

I do have a C# project with many windows  forms. Also I have a separate form to search data from the database. All the forms are calling in to one search form by passing required parameter for search and selected results will return back to text box on calling form. I am fine with the passing parameters in to search and finding the values. My question is how do I return back the selected value in to calling form since it is dynamic ? I wrote following code to return value back to one form and this worked well. But it's only for one form. I just want to know how can I make it variable depend on calling form ?

Passing value back to calling form

```
(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1)
.LoadSearchResult(SResult1,SResult2);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `DataTable` filled with the search results.

The `DataTable` can have dynamic columns depending on the calling form.

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (StackOverflows ORM of choice). It is as VERY lightweight ORM that provides a simple interface for querying a database. While it does allow you to map results to Class, it also allows for completely dynamic queries.

Since it returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>` you don't have to worry about about difference in result types. The form that calls the search form knows which properties it needs to access.

```
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    db.Open();
    IEnumerable<dyanmic> results = db.Query("select * from table");
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement observer design pattern.

you can use IObserver and IObservable interfaces and come up with a scalable solution.

To know more about observer design pattern, go through

```
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Here is a a very raw example :

```
public class SearchData
{
    private DataTable _result = new DataTable();

    public DataTable Result {
        get { return _result; }
        private set { _result = value; } 
   }

    // simple, provides the search data 
    public SearchData Search()
    {

        // use your own code to search, below code is only for a test purpose

        _result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
        _result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

        DataRow row = _result.NewRow();

        row["Id"] = 1;
        row["Name"] = "Some Name";

        _result.Rows.Add(row);

        return this;
    }
}
```

IObservable :

```
// Search Form : the observable responsible for sending search data back to other forms
public partial class SearchForm : Form, IObservable<SearchData>
{
    private List<IObserver<SearchData>> _observers;

    public SearchForm()
    {
        _observers = new List<IObserver<SearchData>>();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<SearchData> observer)
    {
        if (!_observers.Contains(observer))
            _observers.Add(observer);

        return new Unsubscriber(_observers, observer);
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Search();
    }

    private void Search()
    {
        SearchData newSearch = new SearchData();
        SearchData searchValue  = newSearch.Search();

        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            if (searchValue == null)
                observer.OnError(new Exception("pass some expection"));
            else
                observer.OnNext(searchValue);
        }

    }

}
```

IObserver :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IObserver<SearchData>
{
    private IDisposable _unsubscriber;

    SearchForm _frm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _frm = new SearchForm();    
        this.Subscribe(_frm);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frm.Show();
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        this.Unsubscribe();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        throw error;
    }

    public void OnNext(SearchData value)
    {
        searchDataGrid.DataSource = value.Result;            
    }

    public virtual void Unsubscribe()
    {
        _unsubscriber.Dispose();
    }

    public virtual void Subscribe(IObservable<SearchData> provider)
    {
        if (provider != null)
            _unsubscriber = provider.Subscribe(this);
    }
}
```

Please note that , this is a very quick and dirty example, but gives a good starting point.
I haven't used exception handling properly, don't forget to use it .

This way you can add many as (calling) forms and register with SearchForm and get result back. I'm creating the search form again and again. you can make it global and use it through out the application without re-creating it.

Oops , forgot to add the un-subscriber 
    public class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
    {
        private List> _observers;
        private IObserver _observer;

```
    public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<SearchData>> observers, IObserver<SearchData> observer)
    {
        this._observers = observers;
        this._observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_observer != null && _observers.Contains(_observer))
            _observers.Remove(_observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain how the IObservable pattern solves the OP's problem.

Comment: added a quick example code. This can be tweaked and used as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Rabi for the detailed answer.